# Accessing Samba share through Raspberry Pi SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, samba

I have a raspberry Pi at home that I can access over the internet using SSH (using only key authentication), which is behind a TP-Link router. This router has a hard drive attached to it, which I can access as a samba share locally using the router's IP address.
I would like to access this hard drive when I'm away from home, but I don't want to expose my samba share to the internet (needless to say why). Is there a way I can access it securely through my Raspberry Pi's SSH server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, if this is what you want. But what you can do:

1. Mount your router drive via samba to your RPi's mount point.
2. Access your PRi via sshfs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS

Works for me like a charm. I found that using sshfs is much easier than nfs or samba under Linux. This solution definitely works when you access your RPi under Linux. Windows -> RPi, or Mac -> RPi.... perhaps, I don't know. I think there are sshfs solutions, but I don't know how stable or usable they are.

Comment: What is useful with sshfs is that you do not need to add extra tools as it uses only the SSH connection so you don't overload the Raspberry. And also you can just access a part of the drive
On the other side you need to install extra software on the local machine to have support of sshfs. Not always possible if you don't own the machine.

Comment: Also i confirm it works on a Mac, using it at home

Comment: **On the other side you need to install extra software on the local machine to have support of sshfs.** Yes, but isn't this also true for samba? Or nfs?

Comment: Great solution ! I have a usb drive attached directly to the Pi, and it's mounted automatically at startup by OpenElec, and this is how I access it, but I haven't thought about mounting the samba share as a folder in RPi.
I use WinSCP on Windows, and Fx on Android, and both work flawlessly.

Comment: With samba i think (must be confirmed) that support for shares are included by most operating systems. SSHfs is not ... yet.